# Java JMenuItem ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I need some help with my ActionListener on my JMenuBar.

There's no error; however every time I click on a JMenuItem, it triggers all the action associated with the JMenuItem. My question is: am I doing it right in my ActionListener code? I'm not too sure about my ActionListener class. I'm trying to separate my ActionListener from my Button logic.

If anyone has any ideas on what I may be doing wrong, please point it out.

Here is my code:

```
package MenuBar;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SimpleMenuBar{
    private static final LayoutManager grid = new GridLayout(0, 1);
    public JMenuBar MenuBar;
    public JMenu MenuFile, MenuEdit, MenuOption;
    public JMenuItem ItemNew, ItemOpen, ItemSave, ItemExit, ItemCopy, ItemCut, ItemPaste;
    ButtonGroup direction;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem forwardradio, backwardradio;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem CheckCase;
    String input = null;
    public void Design()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Menubar");
        frame.setSize(320, 320);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        MenuBar.setLayout(grid);

        //Menus
        MenuFile = new JMenu("File");
        MenuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        MenuBar.add(MenuFile);

        //sub Menus
        ItemNew = new JMenuItem("New", KeyEvent.VK_N);
        MenuFile.add(ItemNew);
        ItemNew.setActionCommand("New");
        ItemNew.addActionListener(new MenuBarMethod());

        ItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open", KeyEvent.VK_O);
        MenuFile.add(ItemOpen);
        ItemOpen.setActionCommand("Open");
        ItemNew.addActionListener(new MenuBarMethod());
        MenuFile.addSeparator();


        ItemSave = new JMenuItem("Save", KeyEvent.VK_S);
        MenuFile.add(ItemSave);
        MenuFile.addSeparator();

        ItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X);
        MenuFile.add(ItemExit);

        MenuEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        MenuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        MenuBar.add(MenuEdit);

        ItemCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy", KeyEvent.VK_C);
        KeyStroke ctrlCKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C");
        ItemCopy.setAccelerator(ctrlCKeyStroke);
        MenuEdit.add(ItemCopy);

        ItemCut = new JMenuItem("Cut", KeyEvent.VK_V);
        KeyStroke ctrlVKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control V");
        ItemCut.setAccelerator(ctrlVKeyStroke);
        MenuEdit.add(ItemCut);

        ItemPaste = new JMenuItem("Paste", KeyEvent.VK_Y);
        KeyStroke ctrlYKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Y");
        ItemPaste.setAccelerator(ctrlYKeyStroke);
        ItemPaste.setEnabled(false);
        MenuEdit.add(ItemPaste);
        MenuEdit.addSeparator();

        MenuOption = new JMenu("Option");
        Icon atIcon = new ImageIcon("option.png");
        MenuOption.setIcon(atIcon);
        MenuOption.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

        direction = new ButtonGroup();
        forwardradio = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Forward Me", true);
        forwardradio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        MenuOption.add(forwardradio);
        direction.add(forwardradio);
        MenuEdit.add(MenuOption);

        backwardradio = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Backward Me");
        backwardradio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        MenuOption.add(backwardradio);
        direction.add(backwardradio);

        MenuOption.addSeparator();

        CheckCase = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Case Sensitive");
        MenuOption.add(CheckCase);
        direction.add(CheckCase);
        MenuEdit.add(MenuOption);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                SimpleMenuBar MyMenu = new SimpleMenuBar();
                MyMenu.Design();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's an awful lot of code for just a menu bar. I haven't fully implemented the ActionListener. For testing purposes, I've only implemented it for two items: `ItemNew` and `ItemOpen`. Unfortunately, every time I click on the `ItemNew` menu item, it triggers the actions of both `ItemNew` *and* `ItemOpen`.

Here are is code for my action listener:

```
package MenuBar;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MenuBarMethod implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if("New".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected Item: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if("Open".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected Item: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just as a matter of style you should camel case your variables and methods (menuFile, itemSave, itemOpen, ). Classes are Pascal case (MenuBarMethod).

Comment: i'm newbie to java, anyway thank for the naming convention.

Comment: So when you click Open or New does a message dialog popup? Another thing, since your MenuBarMethod action listener handles all the actions (at least these two) you done't need to create a new instance for each menu item. Create one instance and add it to the menuitems. `ActionListener l = new MenubarMethod();  openMenuItem.addActionListerner(l); newMenuItem.addActionListener(l);`

Comment: yes popup will show, by the way thanks a lot it's working now, i tried your code, i see my error i only need to instantiate the class actionlistener once, and call it to my menus. thanks

Comment: it's better if you provide a picture of the JMenu after executing your code

Answer (score 11):

As a matter of personal preference, I prefer to use the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) API

The main reasons are

- It centralise logic associated with a particular action, including name, key stroke, short cuts, icons etc
- It's reusable.  It's much easier to create an `Action` Object then it's to have recreate the menu item & the tool bar item & the popup menu item
- It's well supported by other Swing components.  Most Swing components that support the `ActionListener` API generally provide the means to supply an `Action` as well (`JMenu.add(Action)`, `JMenu(Action)` etc)
- It makes your code easier to read, much easier to read a single `ActionPerformed` method of an `Action` class then try and skim through multiple `if` statements

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

IMHO

Comment: I typically use this as well as it tends to be more reusable. Especially for menuitems used a lot such as "Save", "Save As", "Open", "Print" etc. +1

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `getSource` method of `ActionEvent` instead of `getActionCommand`.

```
public class MenuBarMethod implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == ItemNew){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected Item: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if(e.getSource() == ItemOpen){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected Item: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }
}
```